# Strange inbound MMS messages

Tags: phone, spoofing, sms

We received some strange inbound MMS messages on our Twilio account today. Our account was not compromised, as there are no suspicious outbound messages sent from our number via Twilio.

We first received a message from a Google Voice number containing a suspicious link like

```
https:(slash)(slash)sugarxpartner(dot)com(slash)(randomstring)?t=Horny
```

Shortly after that we received a series of messages from two different MetroPCS numbers that are different by only one digit. Although they are inbound, these messages appear to be a conversation. Messages we received from one MetroPCS number appear to be responses to messages we received from the other MetroPCS number.

All of the messages are MMS messages, but have no media attached that I can see in Twilio.

I believe someone was spoofing the callerid on outbound messages so they appeared to come from our Twilio number. Its possible one of our phone operators or some software opened the suspicious link in the initial message. We received an identical message on a different Twilio number that we do not monitor, and did not receive any subsequent messages.

How can this be prevented in the future? And how are these two MetroPCS numbers able to have a conversation by sending messages to our number?